# iron:router doesn't work after updating meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I recently updated my meteor project and whenever i try to run my project i got this :

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('Home', {
    data: function () { return Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id}); }
  });
});
```

this is my route that should direct the user to "main" template

```
Router.route('/', {
    template: 'main'
});
```

i used to get similar problem when i first added iron:router package, and the reason was because i haven't implemented it. I believe the way i should implement it is different after the update. please correct me if am wrong

Comment: I think it would help if you show what error message you are getting.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen no error, its like telling me i don't have the router implemented!

Comment: You need to give us more info. First, where you're defining your routes ?

Comment: @DiogoMartins inside /lib folder

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi there's just not enough here to go on.

Comment: @MichelFloyd what other information i can provide? i used to get similar problem when i first added iron:router package, and the reason was because i haven't implemented it. I believe the way i should implement it is different after the update. correct me if am wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your router file needs to be included above or in a folder above your client and server folders. It's just there, if router is not contained above client and server than meteor does not digest it properly for the function it serves.

Short answer:
**Put router.js where-ever it is that you start your meteor application.**

(as opposed to `.\client` or `.\server`)

Answer (score 0):

How you configure main template:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'yourMainTemplateName'  //main template should have {{> yield}} inside HTML which tells iron:router where to render templates per route
});
```

Route configuration:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('homeTemplateName');
});
```

Update your question with your new codes if it doesn't work.